# How to convert to exe properly?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

i'm using pyinstaller to convert .py to .exe but i recieve a windows msg :

***failed to execute script***

and my program has no directory or img...

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You write C++ program which loads .py from resources.